# ": No such file or directory"

Tags: python, linux, unix, ubuntu, ubuntu-12.04

Ubuntu version:12.04
Python version:2.7.3

I have a script (prawn.py) that starts out:

```
#! /usr/bin/env python
from random import choice
import os
from webbrowser import open_new
import urllib
print("!")
def getsource(url): page=urllib.urlopen(url);sourcecodey=page.read();page.close;return sourcecodey
#etc
```

When I run it in terminal:

```
$ ./prawn.py
: No such file or directory
```

When I change the firstline to #! /usr/bin/python

```
$ which python
/usr/bin/python
$ ./prawn.py
bash: ./prawn.py: /usr/bin/python^M: bad interpreter: No such file or directory
```

But when I run it using "python prawn.py", it works.

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 5):

The `^M` indicates you're using DOS line endings. Use UNIX line endings instead. You can try to transform your file from DOS line endings to UNIX line endings using `sed` like this:

```
sed -E 's/\'$'\r''$//' < prawn.py > prawn.unix.py
```

The converted file will be in `prawn.unix.py`.

Comment: Thank you so much! I forgot I wrote this on Windows.
I did it the longer way before I saw your edit

Comment: if [dos2unix](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/natty/man1/dos2unix.1.html) is installed, using it would be easier than that sed call.

Answer (score 1):

It seems there is an `^M` in your shebang line, delele all the content of your first line, then retype it (`#!/usr/bin/env python`) by hand.

Answer (score 1):

It is essentially the same error: your shebang line ends with a Carriage Return `\r`/`^M`. `env` prints that out (it prints `python`, it does a carriage return and prints at the beginning of the line  `: No such file or directory`.

If you call `python` directly, `python^M` is not found.

For both cases, remove that extra character; the version with `env` is the better one once you made it work.